# How to set the background color of little box in Tkinter Checkbox widget

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

When I tried to add a color scheme to my Tkinter (Tix) GUI there is a strange side effect where the background color of the little box in a Checkbox widget changed to a maroon color (or something very close) making it difficult to see the black check.
This occurred after I added the following line in the program's **init**:

```
self.tk_setPalette(background=u'AntiqueWhite1', activeBackground=u'peach puff')
```

this works well for most everything except the menubar. Without this line, the little checkboxes all have the normal white background, but with it, they all turn 'maroon'. I also tried adding most of the other tk_setPalette options including 'troughColor' but nothing worked.

Let me know how to override the color of the little checkbox or is there a better way to set up a basic color scheme.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `selectcolor` is what you are looking for. It changes the color of that little box a.k.a selector.

```
c = Checkbutton(master, ... ,selectcolor="blue") #instead of name, it can be #RGB
```

Comment: Well I guess I tried all the other options except that one in tk_setPalette. That worked, thanks, but I still don't understand why the color was set to maroon in the first place when I applied tk_setPalette.